# Can I use a Divination wizard's Portent through a Scrying spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, wizard, divination

If a Divination wizard targets a creature with the *scrying* spell, and the creature is about to make a roll, could the wizard use the Portent feature to affect the result?

Comment: Related: "[Can a Divination wizard in the Border Ethereal use the Portent feature to influence rolls of creatures on the Material Plane?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/115858)"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Even if you can only see a creature because of *scrying* you can still use Portent on their rolls

The [*scrying*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/scrying) spell states (emphasis mine):

> [...] **You can see** and hear **a particular creature** you choose that is on the same plane of existence as you. [...]

Thus, the *scrying* spell allows you to see a creature, and that is all that is required to use the Portent feature as it states (emphasis mine):

> [...] You can replace any attack roll, saving throw, or ability check **made by you or a creature that you can see** with one of these foretelling rolls. [...]

There is no range restriction on the Portent feature, only a visibility restriction.

---

#### This is also addressed in the Sage Advice Compendium

The [Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf) states:

> Q. Can a School of Divination wizard on the Ethereal Plane use Portent on a creature that the wizard can see on the Material Plane?
>
> A. Yes. Portent requires you to be able to see the creature, but it has no range restriction.